# Gas logs won't stay lit

Tags: gas, fireplace

I recently (in the last 2 days) installed gas logs in my home. The pilot light stays lit, I crank them up and after about 10ish minutes they sputter and go out(the pilot light stays lit). I turn them up to high they relight and burn for 30 min then sputter and go out... I don't know why it's doing this....any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make and model is this? Would you add a picture of the controller? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: Do you mean the main gas burner shuts off by itself?

Comment: Is this controlled by an old milivolt thermostat?

Comment: sounds like the oxygen sensor might be dirty, and the thermal change confuses it.

Comment: Yes Sir the main burner sputters and goes out, if I turn the knob off and then back on it relights.  All the while the pilot light stays on.